# Change Listview focus

Tags: android, listview

I Want to focus on the next list item when a button(external-not in listitem) clicked of list view.
I tried like this but it doesn't work :

```
vegetableList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, vegList));
vegetableList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
            {
                current_veg_item = vegList[position];
                parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#33cc99"));

                if (save != -1 && save != position)
                {
                    parent.getChildAt(save).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                }
                save = position; 
        }
});
```

Button `OnClickListener` :

```
OnClick{
    vegetableList.setItemChecked(3, true);
}
```

how I can focus the next item of currently selected item when i click  button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mList.performItemClick(
        mList.getAdapter().getView(mActivePosition, null, null),
        mActivePosition,
        mList.getAdapter().getItemId(mActivePosition));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should works but why not working I don't know &
You can try Like this.

```
ItemAdapter itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter (vegList);
list.setAdapter(itemAdapter );



public class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
  ArrayList<String> vegList;
  public ItemAdapter(ArrayList<String> vegList) 
  {
     this.vegList= vegList;
  }

@Override
public int getCount() 
{
    return vegList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) 
{
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) 
{
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_cell, null);


    TextView tvItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvItem);
    tvItem .setText(vegList.get(position));
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             current_veg_item = vegList[position];
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#33cc99"));

            if (prvsview!=null && prvsview!= convertView)
            {
                prvsview.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
            prvsview= convertView; 
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: I think it's just a alternative of what i have already done.
I already done background change when focused.
Think i want is focus the next list item when a external button clicked.

Comment: Yes this is alternative of what you done. And I did't get your Que Properly And this what you posted is not working so Ihad tell u altenative method.

Comment: Yes, it work you can try.
Declare `int save = -1` variable globally.